# Are there any free implementations of an online 2D orthogonal strip packing algorithm?

Tags: strip, packing

I hasten to add that "online" here refers to a type of algorithm that deals with one object at a time, and doesn't analyze the entire collection before placing them.

I have a lot of images of differing sizes from a webcomic, that I plan to print on a roll of paper, so they need to be packed reasonably well. So called "offline" algorithms however, have a tendency to pack all large blocks towards one end, and all small to the other, and this is not something I'd want.